# can anyone help me out in embedding an autocomplete feature inside a ckeditor dialog box

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, jquery-autocomplete

can anyone help me out in embedding an autocomplete feature inside a ckeditor dialog box

Basically what i want is a simple dialog box with just two text fields, one of which should support autocomplete feature much like jquery autocomplete.

I have already created a plugin which pops up the dialog box and tried to use the jquery aotucompl

```
$( "#inoutFieldOfDialog" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
```

but nothing happens.

I have already searched a lot on google and stackoverflow but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.